# In RBR on 3 monitors, how do I get the gear indicator on the middle screen?

Tags: richard-burns-rally

After some effort I managed to get Richard Burns Rally running on 3 monitors using ATI Eyefinity technology (screen resolution 5760 x 1200). I'm using CamHack to "fix" the distorted view but the on-screen indicators still stay at the right-most location. Is there a way to move them in the center? I'd like to have the gear indicator as close to my view as possible.